# Force template on page load

Tags: templates

tell me where to refer to the function to be run once at the start of the page.

Exactly I mean to set a specific template so that every time you open the page always the same template loads without regard to what template was set up in the back.

Comment: If you are in controll of the template files, leaving only your index.php left should route everything to that template file.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite difficult to understand.

Do you mean you want to make generic template pages Programmatically? There are a few ways to do this.

If you have a page built on the backend, you can create a file within your theme folder called page-{page-name}.php. For instance, for a page called about, you should create a file called page-about.php.

If it is a post, the same logic applies, but with single-{post-name}.php.

Alternatively, if you want a template page for several pages under one file, you could use a conditional statement along with the is_page() function inside page.php (or single.php for posts).

You can also use get_post_field with a conditional, as such:

```
if ('contact-us' == get_post_field( 'post_name', $post->post_parent )) {
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/contact', 'page' );
  exit;
} else if ('volunteer-with-us' == get_post_field( 'post_name')) {
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/contact', 'page' );
  exit;
}
```

Comment: sorry for the language. I think I explained it too twistily.
I am looking for a solution that will allow me to set a specific template defined in the code when opening a website.
Later while browsing the page the template may change but I would like the code to re-set the previously set template after reopening the page.